# Use MySQL in development and SQL Server in production

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to work with mysql on my local computer and SQL Server on production server.

Here is what I've tried to do in `Startup.cs`:

I have two methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to put one of this lines in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL("..."));
```

or

```
services.AddDbContext<pluginwebContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

But `ConfigureServices` does not provide env parameter so I cannot test with:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
```

Comment: set `env` as a field in the class to give you access to it. it can be set in the constructor

Comment: You should you same database vendor locally and in production. Otherwise it basically won't work. You can use free [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) or built-in [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the hosting environment into startup and set as a field/property in the class to give you access to it.

Reference [Application startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)

> The `Startup` class constructor accepts dependencies defined by the host. A common use of dependency injection into the `Startup` class is to inject `IHostingEnvironment` to configure services by environment:

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) {
            // Development configuration
            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL("..."));
        } else {
            // Staging/Production configuration
            services.AddDbContext<pluginwebContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("...");
        }
    }
}
```

There is also an alternative option provided in the link where you use a convention-based approach.